# Determining if string contains same word more than once using Python?

Tags: python, string, cpu-word, unique-values

I have strings with owner names and I need to identify whether they contain a last name twice.

For example, I may have an owner name that reads "**BENNETT** MCCARL & ARNETTE **BENNETT**".

I would like to return True if any word is found in the string twice, and False if all words in the string are unique.

Does anyone know how I can do this using Python?

Comment: This question has arisen from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179164/need-to-find-strings-that-contain-the-same-word-twice, and so its terminology needs some work.  I'll try to do that now.

Answer (score 6):

```
def check(name):
    words = name.split()
    return (len(words) > len(set(words)))
```

You can split the name into a word list by spaces, and then transform this list into a set. Its length will become shorter after duplicated words has been eliminated.